# javascript comparing an array to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, loops

I have some angular code that I am working on.  The goal is to use as little angular 1.x functionality as possible since this will be getting refactored soon.

I am comparing an array

```
  let subscription = [
  "Cinemax Subscription", 
  "Disney Subscription", 
  "Encore Subscription", 
  "Epix Subscription", 
  "HBO Subscription", 
  "MLB Subscription", 
  "NBA Subscription", 
  "NHL Subscription", 
  "Division"
]
```

to an array of objects with a key value relationship that houses another array.

```
let profiles = [
    {
        name:"1+ Adults in Household",
        qualifiers: [
            {
                name: 'Number of adults in the household'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: '75k',
        qualifers: [
            {
                name: 'Division'
            },
            {
                name: 'Income'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Time Warner',
        qualifers: [
            {
                name: 'Division'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am having a difficult time with the indexes and the looping of this.

```
let = profilesFiltered = [];
```

Initially I tried to use a **filter and angular.for
Each** to compare the arrays.

```
let filteredProfiles = subscription.filter( function (src) {
    angular.forEach(profiles, function (key, index) {
        if(src === key.qualifiers[index].name) {
            profilesFiltered.push(key);
        }
    })
});
```

I am seeing inside the if statement that

```
key.qualifiers[index].name // 'Number of adults in the household'
```

Starts out correct in comparison to

```
subscription[0]   // however, it will continue to 1 on the first object which isn't there.
```

I see how it is starting to fail.  But I am not sure how to get properly loop through the **qualifiers** in the **profiles ** array.

The desired result is as those house **Division** which is the last array item in the index.

```
profilesFiltered = [
    {
    name: '75k',
    qualifers: [
      {
        name: 'Division'
      },
      {
        name: 'Income'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
      name: 'Time Warner',
      qualifers: [
          {
              name: 'Division'
          }
      ]
  }
]
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated at this point.

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is, at least for me, still very unclear. Your code has a lot of mistakes in it. For Example, you are not returning a boolean in your filter function. So your filteredProfiles will always be empty. You are not running through the `qualifiers` array - which is spelled wrong in the objects after the first btw - you are only looking for the first qualifier. ETC. You could provide a small example which is self explaining what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter the profiles, using a combination of `filter()` and `some()`:

```
profiles.filter(v => v.qualifiers.some(q => subscription.includes(q.name)));
```

```js
let subscription = [
  "Cinemax Subscription",
  "Disney Subscription",
  "Encore Subscription",
  "Epix Subscription",
  "HBO Subscription",
  "MLB Subscription",
  "NBA Subscription",
  "NHL Subscription",
  "Division"
]

let profiles = [{
    name: "1+ Adults in Household",
    qualifiers: [{
      name: 'Number of adults in the household'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: '75k',
    qualifiers: [{
        name: 'Division'
      },
      {
        name: 'Income'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Time Warner',
    qualifiers: [{
      name: 'Division'
    }]
  }
]

let res = profiles.filter(v => v.qualifiers.some(q => subscription.includes(q.name)));


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this, checkout my code

```js
let profiles = [
    {
        name:"1+ Adults in Household",
        qualifiers: [
            {
                name: 'Number of adults in the household'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
      name: '75k',
      qualifiers: [
        {
          name: 'Division'
        },
        {
          name: 'Income'
        }
      ]
  },
  {
      name: 'Time Warner',
      qualifiers: [
          {
              name: 'Division'
          }
      ]
  }
];

let subscription = [
  "Cinemax Subscription", 
  "Disney Subscription", 
  "Encore Subscription", 
  "Epix Subscription", 
  "HBO Subscription", 
  "MLB Subscription", 
  "NBA Subscription", 
  "NHL Subscription", 
  "Division"
];

let profilesFiltered = profiles.filter(function (a) {
  // first filter all element in the profiles array 
  // check if their qualifiers array is not empty
  return a.qualifiers.some(function (b) {
    // filter the qualifiers array by checking the property name 
    // is it muching any element from subscription array
    return subscription.indexOf(b.name)!==-1;
  });
});

console.log(profilesFiltered);
```

Comment: Pretty much so.  Thanks!

Comment: Using `filter` at `a.qualifiers.filter...` is not a very good idea. While `some` will stop iterating at the first match, filter will always iterate the whole array. That's unnecessary work.

Comment: You must use !== -1 at indexOf :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working code for your data structure. It is based on using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function. If you need to have no duplicates - [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array).

https://jsbin.com/dexagiresa/2/edit?js,output

```
let profiles = [
{
    name:"1+ Adults in Household",
    qualifiers: [
        {
            name: 'Number of adults in the household'
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: '75k',
    qualifiers: [
        {
            name: 'Division'
        },
        {
            name: 'Income'
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Time Warner',
    qualifiers: [
        {
            name: 'Division'
        }
    ]
}
];



let subscription = [
  "Cinemax Subscription", 
  "Disney Subscription", 
  "Encore Subscription", 
  "Epix Subscription", 
  "HBO Subscription", 
  "MLB Subscription", 
  "NBA Subscription", 
  "NHL Subscription", 
  "Division"
];


var filteredProfiles = profiles.reduce(function (collectedResults, profile) {

    var newResults = profile.qualifiers.reduce(function(foundQualifiers, qualifier) {

        if(subscription.indexOf(qualifier.name) > -1) {
            return foundQualifiers.concat(qualifier.name);
        } else {
            return foundQualifiers;
        }

    }, []);

    return collectedResults.concat(newResults);

}, []);

document.write(filteredProfiles);
```